# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.demo.Hibernate.AccountEntity cannot be cast to com.example.demo.Hibernate.AccountEntity

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, classcastexception

[image]

I use Intelliji, when I debug, get result ok. But when get `Object` in List Object I get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.demo.Hibernate.AccountEntity cannot be cast to com.example.demo.Hibernate.AccountEntity
    at com.example.demo.ApiController.AccountApiController.DangNhap(AccountApiController.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

in picture ...
I also ran the test on the console and the results were accurate. I don't see the difference here.

This is my class Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Account", schema = "dbo", catalog = "Sellphones")
public class AccountEntity {
private int idAccount;
private String username;
private String password;
private String hoten;
private Date ngaysinh;
private String email;
private String phonenumber;
private String address;
private String avatar;
private String type;

@Id
@Column(name = "IDAccount", nullable = false)
public int getIdAccount() {
return idAccount;
}

public void setIdAccount(int idAccount) {
this.idAccount = idAccount;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "Username", nullable = false, length = 50)
public String getUsername() {
return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
this.username = username;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "Password", nullable = false, length = 50)
public String getPassword() {
return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
this.password = password;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "Hoten", nullable = false, length = 100)
public String getHoten() {
return hoten;
}

public void setHoten(String hoten) {
this.hoten = hoten;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "Ngaysinh", nullable = false)
public Date getNgaysinh() {
return ngaysinh;
}

public void setNgaysinh(Date ngaysinh) {
this.ngaysinh = ngaysinh;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "Email", nullable = true, length = 500)
public String getEmail() {
return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "Phonenumber", nullable = false, length = 50)
public String getPhonenumber() {
return phonenumber;
}

public void setPhonenumber(String phonenumber) {
this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "Address", nullable = false, length = 200)
public String getAddress() {
return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
this.address = address;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "Avatar", nullable = true, length = 500)
public String getAvatar() {
return avatar;
}

public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
this.avatar = avatar;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "Type", nullable = true, length = 10)
public String getType() {
return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
this.type = type;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
if (this == o) return true;
if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
AccountEntity that = (AccountEntity) o;
return idAccount == that.idAccount &&
Objects.equals(username, that.username) &&
Objects.equals(password, that.password) &&
Objects.equals(hoten, that.hoten) &&
Objects.equals(ngaysinh, that.ngaysinh) &&
Objects.equals(email, that.email) &&
Objects.equals(phonenumber, that.phonenumber) &&
Objects.equals(address, that.address) &&
Objects.equals(avatar, that.avatar) &&
Objects.equals(type, that.type);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
return Objects.hash(idAccount, username, password, hoten, ngaysinh, 
email, phonenumber, address, avatar, type);
}
}
```

And my hbm.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="com.example.demo.Hibernate.AccountEntity" table="Account" 
schema="dbo" catalog="Sellphones">
<id name="idAccount">
<column name="IDAccount" sql-type="int"/>
</id>
<property name="username">
<column name="Username" sql-type="nvarchar(50)" length="50"/>
</property>
<property name="password">
<column name="Password" sql-type="nvarchar(50)" length="50"/>
</property>
<property name="hoten">
<column name="Hoten" sql-type="nvarchar(100)" length="100"/>
</property>
<property name="ngaysinh">
<column name="Ngaysinh" sql-type="date"/>
</property>
<property name="email">
<column name="Email" sql-type="nvarchar(500)" length="500" not- 
null="true"/>
</property>
<property name="phonenumber">
<column name="Phonenumber" sql-type="nvarchar(50)" length="50"/>
</property>
<property name="address">
<column name="Address" sql-type="nvarchar(200)" length="200"/>
</property>
<property name="avatar">
<column name="Avatar" sql-type="nvarchar(500)" length="500" not- 
null="true"/>
</property>
<property name="type">
<column name="Type" sql-type="nvarchar(10)" length="10" not- 
null="true"/>
</property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

when i remove :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

It woring.. Is that a good idea ?

Comment: This usually indicates a class loading problem, where the same class was loaded through two different classloader. Please post a [mre].

Comment: Can you tell details, is there a way to fix this bug?

Comment: Not without a [mre], and yes there is usually a way to fix this: by ensuring the same classloader gets used (or a shared parent classloader in some cases).

Comment: tell me a way to fix this, pls :(

Comment: when i run it with psvm , it working :(

Comment: Without a [mre] that can reproduce the problem, it is very hard to suggest solutions. However, given you're using Spring, make sure you're not crossing boundaries between contexts. Check which class loader loaded the class of the instance, and which one loaded the class you're trying to cast to, and then try to trace things from there.

Comment: i want cast org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@5c14193a to sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2

Comment: two class loader found : org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@5c14193a , and , sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2